# How to extract image url from a custom XML file?

Tags: xml

I have bunch of XML files which contain link to the posts and images in the following markup:

```
<url>
    <loc>http://sample.com/sample-post</loc>
    <lastmod>2015-12-27T16:42:07-01:00</lastmod>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sample.com/1234/5678.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:title><![CDATA[tag1,tag2]]></image:title>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://sample.com/1234/5678.jpg</image:loc>
        <image:caption><![CDATA[tag1,tag2]]></image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

I want to extract the links to the images and remove the duplicates, but there is no `href` attribute so i can use jQuery to hook into them and extract them. Is there any way to do this with this markup? any help would be appreciated.

P.S: there are multiple answers over the internet for this question, but as i mentioned, my XML lacks a `href` attribute.

Comment: What language does it have to be? You can do this easily using SAX and Java. Look here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html

Comment: The language doesn't matter. it can even be C++ as long as i can compile it without having to include a lot of libraries.

Comment: Go for the Java then. SAX is included so you dont need to import it. API is extremely easy

Comment: Thank you. is there anywhere so i can straightly get started?

Comment: Did you get a chance to try code I wrote? It extracts the links as you wanted.

Comment: Oh yes thank you. i had to set up eclipse, took a while. i marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use SAX parser from Java from the [link I gave](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html#gclmt).

Here is a **basic skeleton** to get you started.
It extracts two URLs from your XMLs.
The skeleton prints out stuff so you know what functions do receive.

```
package xmlparse;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class xmlparse {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                                                  SAXException, IOException {

        File inputFile = new File("images.xml");

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        saxParser.parse(inputFile, new MySAXHandler());
    }
}

class MySAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    String currentQName = "";
    List<String> imageLocList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, 
           String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("startElement got: uri: " + uri);
        System.out.println("startElement got localName: " + uri);
        System.out.println("startElement got Name: " + qName);
        System.out.println("startElement got attributes: " + attributes);
        System.out.println();

        this.currentQName = qName; 
    }


    @Override
    public void characters (char ch[], int start, int length) {
        String s = new String(ch).substring(start, start+length).trim(); 
        System.out.format("  Received characters (s=%d, length=%s): %s%n", 
                start, length, s);

        /* ** Your handling should go here ** */
        if (currentQName.equals("image:loc")) {
            imageLocList.add(s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
        System.out.println("endElement got: uri: " + uri);
        System.out.println("endElement got localName: " + uri);
        System.out.println("endElement got qName: " + qName);
        System.out.println();

        this.currentQName = "";
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("Document ended. Listing URLs:");
        imageLocList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```